# An entire day is missing from my system log, what happened?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, logs, console

I just noticed that an entire day, in which I worked the full day and have activity logs elsewhere, is missing from my macOS system log when viewed with the `log show` command.

Here is an excerpt:

```
2024-02-23 08:32:07.590995-0800 0xd43      Default     0x0                  157    7    runningboardd: (RunningBoard) [com.apple.runningboard:ttl] [xpcservice<com.apple.CryptoTokenKit.pivtoken([osservice<com.apple.ctkd>:190])>:191] termination reported by launchd (2, 9, 9)
2024-02-23 08:32:07.592104-0800 0xd44      Default     0x0                  157    7    runningboardd: (RunningBoard) [com.apple.runningboard:ttl] [osservice<com.apple.apsd>:66] termination reported by launchd (2, 9, 9)
2024-02-23 08:32:07.592144-0800 0xd38      Default     0x0                  157    7    runningboardd: (RunningBoard) [com.apple.runningboard:ttl] [osservice<com.apple.security.agent>:181] termination reported by launchd (2, 9, 9)
2024-02-23 08:32:07.592594-0800 0xacd      Default     0x0                  157    7    runningboardd: (RunningBoard) [com.apple.runningboard:ttl] [osservice<com.apple.locationd(205)>:69] termination reported by launchd (2, 9, 9)
2024-02-23 08:32:07.763936-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 08:32:09.142790-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 08:32:09.234454-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 09:33:09.218771-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 10:33:08.987668-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 11:33:09.068556-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 12:33:08.425020-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 13:40:45.500447-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 14:41:46.626749-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 15:33:08.284574-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 16:33:08.821681-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 17:33:06.577544-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 18:46:17.768210-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 19:37:23.184427-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 20:33:35.544479-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 21:36:27.698451-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 22:46:56.680742-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-23 23:46:10.686244-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 00:35:07.690284-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 01:46:31.654347-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 02:38:59.622109-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 03:43:13.631398-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 04:34:19.624661-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 05:43:01.644581-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 06:47:36.606244-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 07:44:33.100364-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 08:48:45.621311-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 09:44:30.597091-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 10:47:01.690523-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 11:39:29.206058-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 12:40:30.364197-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 13:33:06.515055-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 14:33:09.121611-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 15:35:40.819962-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 16:36:59.535330-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 17:39:51.191734-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 18:40:40.333432-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 19:38:58.497582-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 20:48:56.493608-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 21:34:46.959046-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 22:43:05.428233-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-24 23:41:13.238229-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 00:49:31.401751-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 01:37:13.395058-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 02:43:49.426381-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 03:33:15.417763-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 04:37:42.334964-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 05:40:20.385168-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 06:44:07.359897-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 07:37:25.294353-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 08:42:20.321047-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 09:39:21.273834-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 10:35:15.246133-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 10:42:45.347110-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 10:42:45.927165-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 10:43:18.081451-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system boot: 462840C5-1C46-43BE-ACE8-1198491A546B
2024-02-25 10:43:21.868478-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 10:43:21.888036-0800 0x0        Timesync    0x0                  0      0    === system wallclock time adjusted
2024-02-25 10:43:21.942399-0800 0x967      Fault       0x61                 84     14   tccd: [com.apple.TCC:access] <private> does not appear to be a database we made! Purging it
2024-02-25 10:43:21.945914-0800 0x921      Default     0x0                  46     7    UserEventAgent: (SkyLight) [com.apple.SkyLight:default] Set a breakpoint at SLSLogBreak to catch errors/faults as they are logged.
2024-02-25 10:43:21.945946-0800 0x921      Error       0x0                  46     7    UserEventAgent: (SkyLight) [com.apple.SkyLight:default] Server root port lookup error - bootstrap: unknown service
2024-02-25 10:43:21.958642-0800 0x967      Fault       0x62                 84     14   tccd: [com.apple.TCC:access] Failed to remove file at <private>  Error: <private>
2024-02-25 10:43:21.961688-0800 0x0        State       0x61                 84     14   tccd: tccd database
{
    "ACTIVE_POLICIES" =     (
    );
    "DB_FILE_METADATA" =     {
        FILENAME = "/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db";
        "ST_ATIME" = "2024-02-25 18:43:21 +0000";
        "ST_BIRTHTIME" = "2024-02-25 18:43:21 +0000";
        "ST_CTIME" = "2024-02-25 18:43:21 +0000";
        "ST_GID" = 0;
        "ST_MODE" = 100644;
        "ST_MTIME" = "2024-02-25 18:43:21 +0000";
        "ST_UID" = 0;
    };
    OVERRIDES =     (
    );
    PID = 84;
    POLICIES =     (
    );
    RECORDS =     (
    );
    STATUS = 0;
    UID = 0;
    VERS = 29;
}
2024-02-25 10:43:21.988110-0800 0x923      Default     0x0                  50     8    powerd: [com.apple.powerd:batteryAuth] not supported
2024-02-25 10:43:21.989506-0800 0x9e0      Default     0x0                  98     2    lsd: (LaunchServices) [com.apple.launchservices:default] lsd starting with schema version 5019 for effective user 0
2024-02-25 10:43:21.990622-0800 0x923      Default     0x0                  50     8    powerd: [com.apple.powerd:sleepWake] vm.darkwake_mode: 0 -> 0
2024-02-25 10:43:21.995656-0800 0x9e0      Error       0x0                  98     2    lsd: (LaunchServices) [com.apple.launchservices:db] _CSStoreCreateWithURL failed with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “com.apple.LaunchServices-5019-v2.csstore” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv/com.apple.LaunchServices-5019-v2.csstore, NSURL=file:///var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv/com.apple.LaunchServices-5019-v2.csstore, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000023c4060 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Does anyone know what may have caused this? I noticed this because I saw a gap in resource usage through iStats Menu half way through the 24th of February, so I wanted to see if what happened as I did not shut my computer down. Upon further inspection, I noticed that the 23rd and 24th were both missing from the System Log.

What makes me confused is that the 23rd was a Friday and I was using the computer for work.

Comment: I am confused I can see entries for every hour on 23 and 24 - and an error on 25th. What day is missing

Comment: The Unified Log is heavily thinned. In some cases entries disappear within a few minutes, but most you are interested in last for between a few hours and a few days, depending on how busy you system is.  If you need to keep old log entries, you should create `.logarchive` files with the `log collect` command before they disappear. Recommend https://eclecticlight.co/2018/03/19/macos-unified-log-1-why-what-and-how/ and many more recent posts.

Comment: This happens all the time in Star Trek.

Comment: On the 24th, I was actually using my computer. The fact that only this appeared in the logs seems kind of unusual. Likewise, my iStatsMenu graphs are also blank for that day. I am wondering if somebody may have messed with my computer at some point and then wiped the logs?